# Java: Filtering Panels like a JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jpanel

So I'm working on a school project and it's mostly finished but I can't figure out one part. The app lets you save records into a database and we have a panel where you can view the saved records and select them to fill out a form on the right. I'll cut right to the point and share what I'm trying to replicate.

[image]

Now I have a JTable in the panel just to test out methods like sorting filtering and selecting. However my problem is I have no idea how to make something like this where it can still sort and filter like a table. I tried dynamically creating JPanels based on values pulled from the database and putting them in the table rows, and then hiding the other rows to only show a panel that would look like the above picture, but that didn't work. Is it possible to show a JPanel in a JTable like that, or is there an alternative I can use that still allows fitlering and sorting? I'm open to anything, I just have no idea how to tackle this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "show a JPanel in a JTable...". I think that what you really want to do is to create a JTable and modify the table cell renderers so that they display like you desire. The image part is easy since the default cell renderer handles ImageIcons without modification. The 2nd column, a multi-lined display would require that you have that column's renderer produce a JPanel that shows both items -- not hard to do, and easy to search for.

Comment: I think that would be exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to create a jpanel outside of the table in another class, and use that to pass a jpanel. I didn't know I could use the columns renderer to produce a jpanel though! That should suit my needs. Thanks!

Comment: [For example](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+jtable+cell+multiple+lines&start=10)